# 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am having this problem when building my macOS app and I don't know what's wrong.

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
/Users/gab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flash-geftxscpjlmxndgzdhpuizdnidam/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Flash.build/Debug/Flash.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
/Users/gab/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flash-geftxscpjlmxndgzdhpuizdnidam/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Flash.build/Debug/Flash.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FlashApp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
```

I am trying to build a menu bar app for Big Sur.
I triple-checked the files `AppDelegate.swift` and `FlashApp.swift` and I can't see the problem.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var popover = NSPopover.init()
var statusBar: StatusBarController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let contentView = ContentView()
    popover.contentViewController = MainViewController()
    popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 360, height: 360)
    popover.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
    statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    }
}
```

**FlashApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct FlashApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You either use `@main` or `AppDelegate`, not both. Pick one.

Comment: Wow, there was an easy fix! Thanks!